# Issue getting data sent in send_resp

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So I am trying to just build a plug with some error handling and if the user is not authenticated to send a response.  Here is my code:

```
def unauthorized(conn) do
    respond(conn, response_type(conn), 401, "Unauthorized")
end

defp response_type(conn) do
    accept = accept_header(conn)
    if Regex.match?(~r/json/, accept) do
      :json
    else
      :html
    end
end

defp accept_header(conn)  do
    value = conn
      |> get_req_header("accept")
      |> List.first

    value || ""
end

defp respond(conn, :json, status, msg) do
    try do
      conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
      |> send_resp(status, Poison.encode!(%{errors: msg}))
      |> IO.inspect
      |> halt
    rescue ArgumentError ->
      conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
      |> send_resp(status, Poison.encode!(%{errors: [msg]}))
      |> halt
    end
 end
```

So it is almost working, that Inspect is seeing a

> state: :sent, status: 401

On send, but never sending my error message.

I guess a second question is, what I'd really like to do is save many of these Templates in an error_view.ex file and use Phoenix's render.

Seeing as the macro picks the naming convention with **using** is there a way for me to force a render of a certain View in another module?

I am fairly new to Elixir, so thanks for the help!

EDIT:

So I found **put_view** but that doesn't seem to work, when I have any error code other than 200.

If I do any error code it doesn't seem to send the message back, but just specifically for this plug.  If I do a **put_status** on it anywhere else in my controllers it works completely fine but not here.

Here is the new code:

```
defp respond(conn, :json, status, msg) do
    try do
      conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
      #|> send_resp(status, Poison.encode!(%{errors: msg}))
      |> put_status(status)
      |> put_view(ChatApp.Web.UsersView)
      |> render("error_user_creation.json", string: msg)
      |> IO.inspect
      |> halt
    rescue ArgumentError ->
      conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
      |> send_resp(status, Poison.encode!(%{errors: [msg]}))
      |> halt
    end
 end
```

It is however sending the right body that I am sending over as long as it's a status of 200, if it's anything else it will fail.

EDIT, EDIT:

My code runs perfectly reasonable with a status code of 200, but when putting something else in, it breaks:

It's being called like this:

```
case Accounts.check_token(List.first(token)) do
       {:ok, user} ->
            conn
            |>GeneralUtils.put_private(:user, user)
            |> AuthResponses.unauthorized
        :error ->
            conn
            |> GeneralUtils.put_private(:error, {:error, "You do not have permissions"})
     end
```

Also I know this AuthResponses.unauthorized should be in error, I am just testing currently and this was easier.

Comment: There is a `Phoenix.Controller.get_format/1` function to get a request format. (accept plug will put the format for you in the conn)

Comment: Cool!  I updated my response_type with the get_format function. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess a second question is, what I'd really like to do is save many of these Templates in an error_view.ex file and use Phoenix's render.

Focusing on that, I can answer you directly...
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#render/4

just solves it, you pass the View module as the second argument, the  template related to that View module, and the assigns that you want.

About the Plug for authentication, unless you're creating it as a way to study elixir, I can recommend using [Guardian](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian). Here are a simple article explaining how to use guardian for [api](http://blog.overstuffedgorilla.com/simple-guardian-api-authentication/) and phoenix [html](http://blog.overstuffedgorilla.com/simple-guardian/)

Comment: So that's the same issue, if it's a status of 200 it works great, if it's a status of anything else it will send the status but not the body of text.

I am also not really interested in using Guardian but thanks!  That is actually where I learned how to do what I have already.

Comment: Just to understand clearly, do you want to respond with a code error and add the view that need to be renderd or you want to change the default view for wrong request?

Comment: It was actually working but it ended up being a weird issue with my front-end.

Either way that was a good suggestion and will point someone else in the right direction if someone is searching for the answer to this in the future.